# display XML data in PHP

Tags: php, xml

My XML output looks like this...

How do I display it in PHP?

```
  <row>
        <field name="seat_no">18</field>
        <field name="my_ticket_no">924403</field>
        <field name="pass_nm">abcd</field>
        <field name="pass_age">46</field>
        <field name="pass_sex">F</field>
  </row>

  <row>
        <field name="seat_no">19</field>
        <field name="my_ticket_no">926634</field>
        <field name="pass_nm">VANDANA</field>
        <field name="pass_age">25</field>
        <field name="pass_sex">F</field>
  </row>
```

Comment: ... I don't get it. Why would PHP need to display it? Why not just put it in a file and serve that?

Comment: why not use xml and xsl to display the data in php?

Comment: What do you mean by displaying it in PHP?

Comment: This is probably a valid question asking for how to format / layout raw XML data in PHP. We need more hints as what the end result is supposed to look like, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$data = new SimpleXMLElement('<root><row>
        <field name="seat_no">18</field>
        <field name="my_ticket_no">924403</field>
        <field name="pass_nm">abcd</field>
        <field name="pass_age">46</field>
        <field name="pass_sex">F</field>
  </row>

  <row>
        <field name="seat_no">19</field>
        <field name="my_ticket_no">926634</field>
        <field name="pass_nm">VANDANA</field>
        <field name="pass_age">25</field>
        <field name="pass_sex">F</field>
  </row></root>');
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach($data->row as $row)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    $seat = $row->xpath("field[@name = 'seat_no']");
    echo "<td>".$seat[0]."</td>";
    $tckt = $row->xpath("field[@name = 'my_ticket_no']");
    echo "<td>".$tckt[0]."</td>";
    //and so on...
    echo "</tr>";
}  
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I need to display the data in a normat table format. <table> <tr> <td> 18 </td> <td> 924403</td> <td>abcd</td> <td>46</td> <td> F </td></tr> .(second row here)..</table>